# export to pdf in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an asp.net 3.5 application and I have a page with table form data. I need to export this to pdf with some additional formating. This page also has some images inside the same table and some outside the table. I want these images to be exported to pdf as well. How can I do it in asp.net 3.5? Do I need to use some paid/free third party control(s).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) for this. You basically create some html structure of the content you want to have in your PDF and use iTextSharp to generate the PDF for you.