# how to printing/create pdf files from an asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [export to pdf in asp.net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685215/export-to-pdf-in-asp-net-3-5)

What is a tools can I use to print asp.net pages ? 
Is there any good software to create pdf files for asp.net?
is there any free software that takes care of this?

Comment: Hi, if you found my answer helpful, it would've great if you could mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!  If not, let me know how I can improve it and I'd be glad to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I like Expert PDF (http://www.html-to-pdf.net/).  It converts regular HTML and CSS to a PDF format and opens in the associated reader on your local machine.  Much easier than some of the other generators out there such as iText Sharp which require a lot of time learning the API.  Unfortunately its a paid app, so if your company isn't willing to chip in for the license you might want to look at one of the free libraries.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) offers some good PDF generating functionality, though depending on your exact needs it may be too much.  The best way to find out is to take a look at this page and see what you think: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/reporting-services.aspx

If you don't want to use the Report Viewer control, there is a blog post I've seen that details how you can avoid creating one: http://geekswithblogs.net/bsherwin/archive/2007/04/29/112094.aspx (It's in VB but could easily be converted to C#).

Answer (score 0):

iTextsharp is widely used and of-course  it is free.

Just download the DLL